# Entity Framework | Code First - Get Name Of Created Table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

Is it possible? I know I can get the name, when I've specified the TableAttribute, but it should be possible even so, when I let the framework manage the name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `TableAttribute` or fluent api to define the table name, the name will be inferred from the name of `DbSet` property in the context. The only thing which can modify the name in such case is pluralization convention which is used by default.

So if you have:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The table should be named `Users`.

Comment: so if it was DbSet<User> "SomethingFancyNotEvenEnglish" {get; set;} how would it name the table? still Users?

Comment: No it will probably be `SomethingFancyNotEvenEnglishs`

Comment: The correct answer is Users. EF infers the table name from the type, not the property name.

Answer (score 11):

I ended up with this:

```
public static class DbContextExt
{
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var entityName = (context as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.Name;
        var tableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        return tableAttribute == null ? entityName : tableAttribute.Name;
    }
}
```

It's a hybrid of the two answers here: [DBset tabel name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598857/dbset-table-name).

Comment: This is pretty good. I used your answer to derive one that will handle 2/3 inheritance methods that I'll post shortly.  +1

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do this is to use the `GetTableName` method from the following page: http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/

This includes support for the meta tag and model builder `.ToTable()` changes. The examples on this page basically return the `DbSet` property name which is not necessarily the table name in the database.

For example if you had:

```
DbSet<Config> Settings { get; set; }
```

The code on this page would return "Settings" for a table name when the actual DB table name is "Configs". And you would have the same issues if you used:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Config>().ToTable("UserSettings")
```

Using the code in the provided link alleviates all of these issues. Here it is written as an extension:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        // Get the part of the model that contains info about the actual CLR types
        var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

        // Get the entity type from the model that maps to the CLR type
        var entityType = metadata
                .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type);

        // Get the entity set that uses this entity type
        var entitySet = metadata
            .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
            .Single()
            .EntitySets
            .Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name);

        // Find the mapping between conceptual and storage model for this entity set
        var mapping = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
                .Single()
                .EntitySetMappings
                .Single(s => s.EntitySet == entitySet);

        // Find the storage entity set (table) that the entity is mapped
        var table = mapping
            .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
            .Fragments.Single()
            .StoreEntitySet;

        // Return the table name from the storage entity set
        return (string)table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? table.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should handle Table per Type and Table per Hierarchy inheritance.

See:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

The trick is to walk the inheritance tree until you find an overriden Table attribute or a non-object base type.  This could potentially fail if its possible to inherit from a class that's not mapped to a table...which I'm not sure about.  If you can do [NotMapped] on a class, then we'd just have to alter the GetTableDefType method to walk backwards once in that case.

```
   private static Type GetTableDefType(this Type t, out TableAttribute attr) {
        attr = null;
        if (t == typeof(Object)) { throw new ArgumentException(); }
        var tType = t;
        while (true) {               
            attr = tType.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (attr != null) { return tType; }

            if (tType.BaseType == null || tType.BaseType == typeof(Object)) { return tType; }
            tType = tType.BaseType;
        }
    }
    public static string GetTableName(this DbContext context, Type type)  {
        TableAttribute testAttr = null;
        var baseType = type.GetTableDefType(out testAttr);

        if (testAttr != null) { return testAttr.TableName; }

        var propBinding = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty;
        var objectContext = context.GetType().GetInterface("System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter").GetProperty("ObjectContext", propBinding).GetValue(context, null);
        var objectSet = objectContext.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", new Type[0]).MakeGenericMethod(baseType).Invoke(objectContext, null);
        return ((EntitySet)objectSet.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySet", propBinding).GetValue(objectSet, null)).Name;
    }
```