# ASP.NET Entity Linq

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Searching here I see

```
db.ProRel.RemoveRange(db.ProRel.Where(c => c.ProjectId == Project_id));
```

can be used to remove a set of records.  However, if you want to remove a large number of records, like 1000s or more, you don't want to bring them into memory.  Can Linq do it, or do you do you need to drop into SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bulk delete in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592176/bulk-delete-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd party library called [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) that lets you do a batch to delete a set of specific rows. In your case it would be:

```
db.ProRel.Where(c => c.ProjectId == Project_id).Delete();
db.SaveChanges();
```

Just install this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended) package and execute the code I show above.