# Using pluralised table names with C# generics in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to create a **generic function** that will be used to access multiple tables in my database.  Is there a way to used pluralised (pluralized for the non-British!) table names with my generic function.

I may be thinking about this the wrong way (fairly new to generics/templates), but here's my code (`Db` is just a global var for access to my database):

```
public void UpdateMyTables<TEntity>() {
    // string plural = EntityObject<TEntity>.GetTableName(); // OR SOMETHING SIMILAR??
    IEnumerable<EntityType> entitiesToUpdate = Db.<TEntity>; // Obviously doesn't work because TEntity is not a table name, it's an object type

    foreach(<TEntity> e in entitiesToUpdate) {
        e.MyColumn = "A string that I'm updating all these fields with";
    }
}
```

So my question is: do I need to do some hackery to get the pluralised table name, or is there a function designed to return this (like GetTableName), or should I come at this from a different angle?

I also found a link that would help with the manual conversion here: [Pluralising in mvc](http://naspinski.net/post/Pluralize.aspx)

Hugs and kisses and thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm guessing this should be tagged #Entity-Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.Set()` method to get the IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToUpdate = Db.Set<TEntity>();
```

To get the Table Name you could possibly use the code from this [blog post](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/entity-framework-get-mapped-table-name-from-an-entity/) or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598857/dbset-table-name).

The `foreach` should be written:

```
foreach(TEntity e in entitiesToUpdate) { // you can use "var" here if you prefer
    e.MyColumn = "A string that I'm updating all these fields with";
}
```

Now, the problem is that `TEntity` does not have a `.MyColumn` property. If you are using this method with entities that inherit from a base class (called for example BaseEntity), which has that property, you can change the method declaration like this:

```
public void UpdateMyTables<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity {
```

This limits you to pass to call this method only with Entities that inherits from BaseEntity, but will give you access to the public properties and methods defined in `BaseEntity`.

To make the code above work, Base Entity should be declared like this:

```
public class BaseEntity { //of course it can be abstract or an interface...
    public string MyColumn { get; set; }
}
```

I hope I understood what you wanted to do. If you need further information let us know. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the extensive answer (+1).  Although I'm having issues with the second half - my `TEntities` inherit from:

`public interface IPreparable<out T> {
     T Prepare(DdqEntities db);
  }` and I can't get rid of the  *TEntity does not have a .MyColumn property* even when adding `where TEntity: IPreparable<T>` like you say above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the interface is what you wrote, meaning that it only has a method `Prepare(...)` then you can only call that method on your generic. I have detailed what the BaseEntity has to look like.

Comment: Ah okay I understand.  I'll have to refactor my code a bit to get this to work.  Thanks again.