# How can I get Class name using Table name on EntityFramework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can get Table name from Entity/Class name but I need to get Class name from Table name.

```
[Table("MyAccount")]
public class Account
{ public string abc {get; set;}}
```

I want to get Account class from controller using "MyAccount" string.

I want to get the class details like class name using table name parameter and DbContext. I don't want to access table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DbSet table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598857/dbset-table-name)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question. Normally you define a `DbSet<Account>` in your `DbContext` and use this set to access the table. No need to pass the table name anywhere!

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

using (var context = new MyDbContext()) { 
    var theAccount = context.Accounts.Find(accountId);
    var abc = theAccount.abc;
}
```

If you need dynamic access, use the `DbContext.Set` method.

```
Type accountType = typeof(Account);
var allAccounts = context.Set(accountType).ToArray();
```

See [Entity Framework Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx).

This answer shows how to get the DbSet by table name: [Dynamically access table in EF Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48041821/1450855)

Comment: I want to get the class details like class name using table name parameter and DbContext. I don't want to access table.